# installing memcached in debian with lemp 7 jetware

Tags: debian, php, nginx, memcached

im trying to install memcached with the following command :

```
curl -L https://jetware.io/appliances/jetware/memcached14-170503/file/installer:nub_tgz/setup | sh
```

I get this error :

```
ERROR Destination directory /jet already exists
```

I'm using this image in google cloud plateform : 
http://jetware.io/appliances/jetware/wordpress4_lemp7-170526